# Повторяющиеся значения переменных и записей в таблице

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день!

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить такую задачу :

- **дано:** неизвестное количество записей в таблице mysql, состоящие из 2 полей - **`hour`, `minute`** и переменные php **$hour и $minute** (любое вменяемое значения, например 12 и 30 соответственно, т.е. 12:30)
- нужно вычислить какие значения получат переменные **$hour и $minute**.
- **условие:** если поля из таблицы совпадают с переменными (например в таблице есть запись где **`hour` = 12 и `minute` = 30** и такие же значения в переменных), то к переменной $hour добавить 1, но опять чтоб в записи muysql небыло такого значения (т.е. в итоге чтоб небыло 13:30, а если есть, то опять прибавить 1 час)

Comment: Что то тут не так "бай дизайн", как говорится. А, простите, с какой целью это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем запрос, выбирающий из таблицы все значения столбца **hour** по такому условию:

```
SELECT DISTINCT hour tablename WHERE hour >= 12 AND minute = 30 ORDER BY hour ASC
```

Обработаем выборку

```
# Предположим, что выборка дала такие часы:
# $hours_from_db = array(12, 13, 14, 15, 17);

# Генерируем все возможные часы, подходящие под условие
$potential = range(12, 23);

# Исключаем часы, выбранные из БД, из возможных решений
# Первый элемент из оставшегося массива и есть решение
# Если решения нет - NULL
$solution = array_shift(array_diff($potential, $hours_from_db));

# Для данного случая ответ - 16
```

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Создать ещё одо поле id и проверять если $hour = допустим 1 и $minute != 10 то добавляем в таблицу. Делая всё в цикле где $i = 1; $i<=24;$i++;

Соответственно:

```
$min = 20;
for($i=1; $i<=24; $i++)
{
  if($hour!=$i) //добавляем час со значением минут 00
  if($i==$hour && $minute!=$min)
  {
   //добавляем запись
  }
}
```

но я бы организовал справочник где

--таблица часов
id | hour

-- таблица минут
id | minute

-- таблица связи

id_ hour | id_minute

Но вопрос Для чего такие сложности вам?

Comment: мне нужно не добавить запись в базу, а получить результат в переменных $hour и $minute, чтоб часы не совпадали с часами в базе, а если совпадали, то часы увеличить на 1

Comment: И чем вам не подходит мной приведённый пример логики? Уберите for оставьте if и вы получите то что вам надо

Comment: Можно так:

    $h = 0;
    if($h==$hours_db) $h+=1;

Где $h вменяемое значение часа...
Хотя можно сделать так

    $query = "SELECT hour WHERE hour=$h";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    
    $h = $row['hour']+1;

Comment: эта логика тоже не подходит, т.к. нужно еще раз проверить есть ли значение часов, когда мы увеличим на 1. Т.е. переменная равна 12, в базе есть значения 12,13,14,15. В тоге в переменной должны получить значение 16 (т.е. максимальное от значения в таблице). Но могут быть и такие записи в таблице 12,13,15,. Тогда должно значение получится 14, т.к. в базе оно отсутствует

Comment: ну и что мешвет сделать так?

    $query = "SELECT hour WHERE hour=".($h+1);

где $h - это час, вводимое пользователем число. И если этот час+1 не присутствует в таблице выводить его или записывать в таблицу если присутствует то не плюсовать 1 а выводить час и введённые минуты... и больше никаких проверок делать ненужно!